# How to Arrange the x axis on a Plotly Bar Chart with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly, bar-chart

Please opine on how the order of the x axis on a Plotly bar chart can be arranged.

I am using a toy example with the diamond dataset and trying to arrange clarity by ascending mean depth. I am very familiar with ggplot but quite new to plotly. I have seen some postings online regarding this issue but none seem to be definitive. After rendering the plot, I think that the clarity categories are indeed ordered correctly, hovering the mouse to get the label values would suggest this, but these values (61.3, 61.3, 61.4, 61.6, 61.7,61.7,61.8, 61.9 for all clarity groups) don't obviously map to the y axis which is on a scale of 0 to 16k. This is confusing me. I am not looking to use the ggplotly  wrapper, I am looking for a plotly solution, thanks.

[image: Plotly Bar Chart with Problematic x axis order and Questionable Y axis Scale]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(321)
my_diamonds <- ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  slice(sample(nrow(.), 1000))

my_diamonds %>%
  group_by(clarity) %>%
  mutate(mean_depth = mean(depth)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  plot_ly(
    data = .
    , x = ~ clarity
    , y = ~ mean_depth
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Mean Depth for each Clarity Category"
    , xaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = ~ reorder(clarity, mean_depth))
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data has not been processed fully prior to plotting.  Once you select the appropriate information, your code plots fine.  I have subtracted 61 from the `mean_depth` as it will be easier to see the bar order.  You can remove the subtraction.  Try this

```
set.seed(321)
my_diamonds <- ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  slice(sample(nrow(.), 1000))

my_diamonds %>%
  group_by(clarity) %>%
  mutate(mean_depth = mean(depth)-61) %>% 
  distinct(clarity,mean_depth) %>%  arrange(mean_depth) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%

  plot_ly(
    data = .
    , x = ~ clarity
    , y = ~ mean_depth
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Mean Depth for each Clarity Category"
    , xaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = ~ reorder(clarity, mean_depth))
  )
```

[image: output]

Comment: Super thanks. For info for others.. I also got it descending with  arrange(desc(mean_depth)) . I though that functionality would be in the categoryarray  = reorder step but it worked in the main dplyr chain.